# Unable to Enable Encryption at host for Azure VM

Tags: azure, encryption, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-extension

I'm attempting to enable Encryption at host for a virtual machine (VM) in Azure. I've confirmed that the "Microsoft.Compute" resource provider is registered in my Azure subscription, and when I run the necessary command to verify, it shows as registered. However, when I try to enable encryption at the host level for the VM's disk, I encounter the following error:

```
Failed to update 'abc-vm'. Error: The property 'securityProfile.encryptionAtHost' is not valid because the 'Microsoft.Compute/EncryptionAtHost' feature is not enabled for this subscription
```

Is there a specific solution or additional troubleshooting step I should consider to enable host-level encryption successfully? Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is off-topic here - it's not a programming question. Probably fits better on [sf]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Enable Encryption at host for Azure vm you can follow the below steps:

Ensure that it is registered for your subscription like below:

```
Register-AzProviderFeature -FeatureName "EncryptionAtHost" -ProviderNamespace "Microsoft.Compute"
```

```
Get-AzProviderFeature -FeatureName "EncryptionAtHost" -ProviderNamespace "Microsoft.Compute"
```

[image]

As per [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disks-enable-host-based-encryption-powershell#finding-supported-vm-sizes) make sure that you are selecting the correct vm size.

To check the supported vm size to allow Encryption at host make use of below script.

```c
$vmSizes=Get-AzComputeResourceSku | where{$_.ResourceType -eq 'virtualMachines' -and $_.Locations.Contains('eastus')} 

foreach($vmSize in $vmSizes)
{
    foreach($capability in $vmSize.capabilities)
    {
        if($capability.Name -eq 'EncryptionAtHostSupported' -and $capability.Value -eq 'true')
        {
            $vmSize

        }

    }
}
```

***Output***:

[image]

After ensuring the above steps, I am able to create virtual machine with enabled Encryption at host like below:

[image]

If error persists, send an email to `encryptionAtHost@microsoft.com` with your subscription Ids to get the feature enabled for your subscriptions.

***Reference***:

[Unable to enable encryption at host · Issue #68028 · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/68028) by *DerekHerman-MSFT*

Comment: what we can do in the case of existing VM ?

Comment: you can enable Encryption at host for your existing VM First using the above cmd registered in ur subscription wait about 15 minutes for the feature to finish registering. Now deallocate the vm -> click on disk -> additional setting like [this](https://i.imgur.com/EHxmPuY.png)  you can enable Encryption at host check [this](https://i.imgur.com/7InRaqS.png)

Comment: Yes Encryption Enabled